# Image with CSS not displaying

Tags: html

This is my HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Will Treston - CPD Showcase</title>
    <meta name="author" content="name">
    <meta name="description" content="description here">
    <meta name="keywords" content="keywords,here">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="index.css" type="text/css">
  </head>
  <body>
  <div id="content" class="content">
    <div id="profile_pic" class="profile_pic">
    </div>
    <div id="overview">
    </div>
    <div id="buttons">

    </div>
  </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

and this is the CSS I am currently using:

```
body {
    min-height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    /* taken from https://css-tricks.com/perfect-full-page-background-image/ */
    background: url("./images/index_background.jpg") no-repeat center center fixed; 
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
    /* end */
}
.content {
    min-height: 100%;
    padding: 10%, 5%, 10%, 5%;
    text-align: center;
    display: inline-block;
}
.profile_pic {
    height: 20%;
    width: 20%;
    background-image: url("./images/profile_pic.jpg");
}
```

Currently, the body class image is displaying as it is meant to be, however the image in the profile_pic class is not. The image is named correctly and the link is 100% correct.

Any help and suggestions would be helpful.

Comment: @ZohirSalak still no change

Comment: Oh right,  you're using percentage value to set  `.profile_pic` height and width, percentage values depends on the element's parent height and width, the parent in this case is `.content` which doesn't have any height or width set, therefore you see nothing.

Comment: Also don't comma separate padding values, a single space is the correct syntax

Comment: this is the css for my .content now ```.content {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 10%, 5%, 10%, 5%;
}``` and it still does not work

Comment: like i said percentage values depends on the parent, the parent of `.content` is the body, the body doesn't have a height set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your problem is with your CSS declaration for your `.content` and `.profile_pic` - because you aren't setting a `height` on `.content`, there is nothing for your `height` call on `.profile_pic` to reference for the `height: 20%`.

Here's some modified CSS:

```
body {
    min-height: 100vh;
    height: 100vh; //using view height (vh) units makes it so it's always X% of the visible height
}
.content {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%; //this works because it's direct parent, 'body', has a height. Therefore, this height is recognized as (100% of 100vh, or 100vh).
    padding: 10% 5% 10% 5%;
    text-align: center;
    display: inline-block;
}
.profile_pic {
    height: 20%;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 20%;
    background-image: url("./images/profile_pic.jpg");
}
```

You don't need to use `vh` units, but the problem here is that your `.profile_pic` is 20% of the height of 0 (since `.content`, it's direct parent, doesn't have a height defined).

Also, as a side note, your `padding` call on `.content` is incorrect - you don't need the commas.

Comment: Glad I could help! Relative Units in CSS are kind of finicky - here's a good resource for understanding the different unit types, and how they work together!

[CSS Relative Units](https://thecssworkshop.com/lessons/relative-units)